# Flexbox - sizing col w/multiple rows to fit adjacent col w/single row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flexboxgrid

Huge thanks to anyone who can help.

I'm trying to grid using Flexbox and it's working great except when I try to create 2 columns side by side with the following scenario:

- 1 column has a single image in it (cropped to fill the column)
- 1 column has multiple rows in it (combination of images and text)
- both columns are the same height

I've included 2 pictures below that hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do. Ironically, a  element with row-span would do the trick, but I want the responsiveness that flexbox provides.

Hopefully the images attached make it clear.  Any help is appreciated!!

Example image: [3 stacked items next to 1 item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnrQA.png)

Example image: [2 stacked items next to 1 item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTcPL.png)

I'm using Bootstrap and it loads on my site here: https://www.larsbot.com/ but the row is not growing in height as expected.  A cleaner version of my code otherwise so far is below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md" style="background: grey;">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/02_01.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md" style="background:red;">I want this text and to fill up the remaining height of it's parent column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md"><img style="object-fit: cover;" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/02_02.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md"><img style="object-fit: cover;" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/02_03.png" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As we can't debug images, post a minimal working code snippet.

Comment: Added - sorry bout that

Comment: you should also give the CSS for your row and col-md classes

Comment: I've tried setting up a jsfiddle(?) with the HTML and CSS and I can't seem to get the CSS to load at all.  It's live in a spectacularly ugly way on my site here: https://www.larsbot.com/